# Which is the best language to replace objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

After reading [Is a virtual machine for Cocoa programming inevitable?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/is-virtual-machine-for-cocoa.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+CocoaWithLove+%28Cocoa+with+Love%29&utm_content=Google+Reader), I'd like know what is *the* language in your mind if the replacement really happens, and why?

> Fixable complaints in the language and APIs include
>
> - the lack of tuples, slices, maps or associations at a syntax level;
> - the lack of template programming;
> - the lack of namespaces;
> - the lack of default parameters to methods;
> - the lack of operator overrides/overloading;
> - leaks and premature collection by the garbage collector;
> - the wordy, camel-coded naming conventions;
> - the lack of package management;
> - the lack of out-of-the-box support for "business" APIs like REST, SOAP, SQL, etc.
> - Even the commonly mocked square bracket method invocation syntax could be changed if the need existed.

p.s. one language per answer please.

Comment: Asking for the *best* language without any specific requirements is not going to lead anywhere.

Comment: @Georg This question assumes the new language will solve the problems stated in the linked article.

Comment: Ah, maybe you could summarize them here then?

Comment: @Georg, "Fixable complaints in the language and APIs include the lack of tuples, slices, maps or associations at a syntax level; the lack of template programming; the lack of namespaces; the lack of default parameters to methods; the lack of operator overrides/overloading; leaks and premature collection by the garbage collector; the wordy, camel-coded naming conventions; the lack of package management; the lack of out-of-the-box support for "business" APIs like REST, SOAP, SQL, etc. Even the commonly mocked square bracket method invocation syntax could be changed if the need existed."

Comment: - the lack of code-level security checks
 - lack of boxing
 - relatively poor type safety

Comment: There is no objective answer to this question, and it's looking a bit argumentative.  Voting to close.

Comment: @David, what if you're the language designer in Apple and Steve Jobs gives you a mission: "build a better language".

Comment: @Horace Ho:  If the question becomes objective when Steve Jobs asks it, he can post it here.  In its present form, it's highly subjective.

Comment: @Horace Ho:  Some people would say there should be no `subjective` tag.  I'm not that strict, but at some point it's not really possible to provide useful answers.  The exact location of this line is fuzzy, but in my opinion this question is over it.  Since nobody else seems to have joined me in a close vote, don't worry about it.

Comment: @David, I don't really understand why you say there will not be an `useful` answer for this question. Those who open this question are probably have some knowledge of objective-c. Most programmers are usually exposed to more than one language. That's why I expect someone will suggest some language may do a better job than objective-c. As we see, Apple is introducing `blocks` and so there must be room for improvement. So even "`objective-c + lambda`" can be an `useful` answer. I really don't understand your pessimistic comment about usefulness of this question.

Answer (score 5):

How valid are the complaints:

> Fixable complaints in the language and APIs include
>
> - the lack of tuples, slices, maps or associations at a syntax level;

So what?

> - the lack of template programming;

Is this C++ templates?  Then use Objective-C++.  Personally, I think it's a plus point that we don't have them in Objective-C.

> - the lack of namespaces;

This one is valid.  I'd dearly love name spaces.

> - the lack of default parameters to methods;

This is another feature I am glad is not in Objective-C

> - the lack of operator overrides/overloading;

This is another feature I am glad is not in Objective-C

> - leaks and premature collection by the garbage collector;

So fix the garbage collector bugs.

> - the wordy, camel-coded naming conventions;

I like the wordy naming conventions.  It makes the code easier to read.  OTOH if you are a person who doesn't note thatthese are only *conventions*.  The compiler doesn't force you to use them.

> - the lack of package management;

Packages would be nice.

> - the lack of out-of-the-box support for "business" APIs like REST, SOAP, SQL, etc.

There are plenty of libraries available for these.

> - Even the commonly mocked square bracket method invocation syntax could be changed if the need existed.

Commonly mocked by people who don't really use the language. When I first started C I hated a lot about the syntax, but you get used to it.

I see no pressing reason to change anything about Objective-C except to add name space support.  So that's my answer:  Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

MacRuby, an implementation of Ruby that uses the LLVM compiler and bases all of its objects on the Objective-C runtime library (and on normal Cocoa classes like `NSString`, `NSArray`). It's completely interoperable with ObjC so existing code can be integrated with MacRuby code. Indeed ObjC could be used as a systems programming language in the same way that the JVM and parts of the Java class library are written in C, not Java.

Essentially I think any replacement language must be interoperable with Objective-C, will be object-oriented, and will have completely managed access to memory.

Comment: as demonstrated by the iphone wax project, how's lua compare to ruby, in terms of interoperability?

Comment: @Horace don't know, I have no experience with Lua.

Comment: Ruby has strong object orientation, Lua doesn't, so in that respect I would expect Ruby to be a better match. Apart from that, there are various pros and cons for both, but in general, I expect MacRuby to be an exceptionally strong platform for writing OS X apps.

Comment: Given the amount of resources Apple is throwing behind MacRuby, I'd better dollars to doughnuts that MacRuby would be Objective-C's replacement *if* Apple decides to ditch Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-but-not-C, a language that borrows a lot of syntax and methodology from Objective-C but does away with the direct access memory model and primitive arrays. It would be an entirely new language designed by Apple with compatibility (probably even binary compatibility) with the Objective-C runtime library.

The result would be a to Objective-C as Microsoft Managed C++.NET is to C++. In fact, if Apple were to use a VM like LLVM in the same way that Microsoft uses the .NET CLR, then other languages such as Ruby, Python etc. could easily interoperate with "Objective-but-not-C" code.

Comment: Why not just call the language "Objective"?

Comment: @JAB: because "SmallTalk" is a more accurate name.

Comment: In other words, given your comparison, the result would be a hack job dropping features of Objective-C to fit into a model it wasn't intended to go into?

Comment: @Graham Lee: Ah, so it'd effectively be a Smalltalk implementation that uses the Cocoa libraries. @David: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk

Comment: @David: yes, because the model Objective-C _was_ intended for is irrelevant in modern computing. Check out Brad Cox's book.

Comment: @Graham Lee:  Your comparison was that it would wind up like "Microsoft Managed C++.NET is to C++".  Managed C++ and C++/CLI are, shall we say, not well respected by C++ experts.

Comment: And C++ experts aren't well respected by Objective-C experts.

Comment: @Graham Lee:  That's a harsh thing to say.  It's true that C++ experts aren't Objective-C experts as a rule, but I don't see why that should imply lack of respect.  I said nothing about Objective-C, only about C++ and your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Swift! Swift is already on it's way to replacing Objective C.

It is easy to learn, extremely OOP, and handles so many things that other languages should.

Once you get a feel for the language, you feel more powerful than almost any other language as far as what you are then capable of.

Garbage Collection is handled for you to where the only time you need worry about it at all is when running asynchronous code.

Virtually all of the points that were made are addressed completely or at least partially inside of Swift besides the wordy naming conventions of which I am a huge fan.

I have met many Objective C developers that don't see the advantage, but as far as I am concerned they are stuck in their old ways.

Final point.... Swift is around 4 times faster than python from my own personal simple math loop tests.